# Fast api with My SQL update table with dynamic variables, I don't know from advance how many variables i'm gonna need to update

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi

i'm just starting with all backend and python but I couldn't find an answer for this.
I'm working with fast API trying to do an update function that receives a user with some parameters to update in the MySQL data base.
The problem is that i'm not sure how or which variables i'm going to receive to update.
I tried a couple ideas that I had but all of them returned me an error, can you help me out please?
Thanks!

Things that tried and returned error:

1_

```
@user.put("/updateuser", response_model=User)
async def update_user(user: User):
    values_update = ""
    try:
        if user.name is not None:
           values_update += "name"
           values_update += user.name
        if user.email is not None:
           values_update += ", "
           values_update += "email"
           values_update += user.email
        if user.password is not None:
           values_update += ", "
           values_update += "password"
           values_update += user.password
        conn.execute(users.update().values(values_update).where(users.c.id == user.id)
        return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == user.id)).first()
    except:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail=conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == id)).first()
        )
```

2_ The same but making the "user.name" also part of the string like `values_update += "user.name"` between quotation marks like a string, and not just the value, and also no.

3_ Also with a dictionary and also nothing. Where `values_update={}` and adding the values to the dictionary on every if.

This was the final one that works fine but I don't think is a good practice to connect to the data base once for every parameter that I want to change, if its not up to 3 and it's up to 10000 parameters? I could take ages:

```
@user.put("/updateuser", response_model=User)
async def update_user(user: User):
    try:
        if user.name is not None:
            conn.execute(users.update().values(name = user.name).where(users.c.id == user.id))
        if user.email is not None:
            conn.execute(users.update().values(email = user.email).where(users.c.id == user.id))
        if user.password is not None:
            conn.execute(users.update().values(password = user.password).where(users.c.id == user.id))
        return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == user.id)).first()
    except:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail=conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == id)).first()
        )
```

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question using code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), it's currently completely unreadable.

Comment: Check out passing `.values(**values_update)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Update.values()` methods [accepts both a dictionary and key/value pairs as its arguments](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update.values).

You can create a dictionary to hold your values:

```py
updated_fields = {}

if user.name is not None:
    updated_fields["name"] = user.name

if user.email is not None:
    updated_fields["email"] = user.email

if user.password is not None:
    updated_fields["password"] = user.password

# either give it a dict
conn.execute(users.update().values(updated_fields).where(users.c.id == user.id))

# or expand it into a key/value set of arguments with the `**` syntax:
conn.execute(users.update().values(**updated_fields).where(users.c.id == user.id))
```

The last version would be expanded to `values(name=.., email=..., ...)` by Python.

But if we look at the code, we can see that we're really repeating quite a few lines of logic (check if not None, then assign to a key). We can generalize this as a helper function (see below for an even easier method if `model` is a Pydantic model):

```py
from typing import Set

def as_update_arguments(model, fields: Set):
    updated = {}

    for field in fields:
        value = getattr(model, field, None)

        if value is None:
            continue

        updated[field] = value

    return updated

# The update method would then be simpler:
async def update_user(user: User):
    updated_values = as_update_arguments(user, {"name", "email", "password"})
    conn.execute(users.update().values(updated_values).where(users.c.id == user.id))

    return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == user.id)).first()
```

Now you can easily re-use the logic of "pick these fields from the model to issue an update for if they're not None".

There's a final option, and that's if you're using Pydantic and you're always making sure that the submission model actually matches what you're expecting (so you want to update all the fields included in the model as it's submitted), you can make Pydantic do the work for you:

```py
async def update_user(user: User):
    updated_values = user.to_dict(exclude_unset=True, exclude_none=True)

    conn.execute(users.update().values(updated_values).where(users.c.id == user.id))

    return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == user.id)).first()
```

No need for a helper function in that case. And if `user` is a Pydantic model that *doesn't* match exactly what you want to allow to update, you can also combine this with the `include` parameter if you only want to extract specific parts of the model object, just as we did in our helper above:

```py
async def update_user(user: User):
    updated_values = user.to_dict(include={"name", "email", "password"}, 
                                  exclude_unset=True, 
                                  exclude_none=True,
                                  )

    conn.execute(users.update().values(updated_values).where(users.c.id == user.id))

    return conn.execute(users.select().where(users.c.id == user.id)).first()
```

Be careful to not have `id` (or similar columns that a user shouldn't be able to change) as a field in your models in this case (or use `include` and make sure that you don't have them in `include` - I prefer having exact models representing what a user can update.